# Fixing python default in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, python

I have three python folders in /usr/lib: python2.7, python3, python3.8 and python3.9
The `python3 --version` command returns the following:

```
Python 3.9.0
```

even though I uninstalled that specific version with

```
sudo apt remove --purge python3.9
```

successfully (or so I thought). I would like to make python 3.8 the default, so that when I type `python3` it gets called up. I tried to follow some of the other answers on the topic, without success.
Not sure if it means anything or if it's supposed to be like that, but the `python` command tells me there's no package with that name.
By the way, I'm on Mint 20 up to date.

Comment: What does `update-alternatives --list python` return?

Comment: it says there are no alternatives for python

Comment: Did you create an alias to python3.9? I would do a quick search for python3.9, both packages and files/directories, just to see what was left behind.

Answer (score -1):

An alias alone might not be enough. Sure you can create one in your .profile and source that before your shell starts but some applications/dependencies my still find 2.7 as your default. This is because of the symlink found in usr/bin. Create a new one in that location and point it to the interpreter you wish to use.